# Comando SQL Server para listar transações ativas

Tags: sql-server

Qual comando no SQL Server que liste as transações ativas no momento?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode consultar os locks, assim:

```
SELECT  L.request_session_id AS SPID,
        DB_NAME(L.resource_database_id) AS DatabaseName,
        O.Name AS LockedObjectName,
        P.object_id AS LockedObjectId,
        L.resource_type AS LockedResource,
        L.request_mode AS LockType,
        ST.text AS SqlStatementText,
        ES.login_name AS LoginName,
        ES.host_name AS HostName,
        TST.is_user_transaction as IsUserTransaction,
        AT.name as TransactionName,
        CN.auth_scheme as AuthenticationMethod
FROM    sys.dm_tran_locks L
        JOIN sys.partitions P ON P.hobt_id = L.resource_associated_entity_id
        JOIN sys.objects O ON O.object_id = P.object_id
        JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions ES ON ES.session_id = L.request_session_id
        JOIN sys.dm_tran_session_transactions TST ON ES.session_id = TST.session_id
        JOIN sys.dm_tran_active_transactions AT ON TST.transaction_id = AT.transaction_id
        JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections CN ON CN.session_id = ES.session_id
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(CN.most_recent_sql_handle) AS ST
WHERE   resource_database_id = db_id()
ORDER BY L.request_session_id
```

[Neste artigo](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/04/29/SQL-Server-2005-Get-full-information-about-transaction-locks.aspx) você vai ter uma visão geral sobre os locks. Foi nele que encontrei sua resposta.

Answer (score 3):

Via Transact-SQL:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    sysprocesses 
WHERE   open_tran        = 1
```

[(Fonte.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449719/is-there-a-way-to-list-open-transactions-on-sql-server-2000-database)

Answer (score 2):

Encontrei este comando também:

```
DBCC OPENTRAN
```